# Quantifying comparison of two different field data sets for the same 3D domain

Tags: correlation, dataset, spatial, paired-comparisons, cross-correlation

I have a 3D domain (say a cube). The cube is discretized into an array of grid points. Each grid point holds a field data (like temperature, temperature gradient etc.).

[image]

I would like to see if the distribution of two different field quantities are correlated in anyway, like say, Does the maximum values occur at the same grid point for both the fields etc.

What are the statistical tools that I could employ in quantifying such comparisons?